# Save output in variable?

Tags: bash, shell

How would I go about saving an output in a vaiable. For example, if I enter:

```
ls -l
```

it will show the files. How would I go about saving the output in a variable? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Your question title mentions C; your tags do not.  There's an answer that's appropriate to the tags - but you can and should edit the title if that's correct.  If you really want to do it in C, there's a deleted answer that's appropriate; you should retag the question, dropping terminal (and review the bash and shell tags).

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:
`var1=$(ls -l)`

Answer (score 2):

I know three ways to do:

**1) Functions are suitable for such tasks:**

```
func (){
ls -l
}
```

Invoke it by saying `func`

**2) Also another suitable solution could be eval:**

```
var="ls -l"
eval $var
```

**3) The third one is using variables directly:**

```
var=$(ls -l)
OR
var=`ls -l`
```

you can get output of third solution in good way:

```
echo "$var"
```

and also in nasty way:

```
echo $var
```

Comment: Actually, the "good" way is `echo "${var}"`